# Is a Binary Tree Contained Within Another Binary Tree - C

Tags: c, search, binary-tree

So I just had an interview that I'm confident I screwed up royally. I had a bunch of questions thrown at me and didn't have enough time to answer the last one.

After getting all beginning questions correct, I was asked to write a function that would determine whether a binary tree b is contained within another binary tree a. I coded the question prior to that correctly, in which he asked me to write a function to determine whether two trees are equal:

```
int sameTree(struct node *a, struct node *b){
//both empty = TRUE
if(a == NULL && b == NULL)
    return TRUE;
//both not empty, compare them
else if(a != NULL && b != NULL){
    return(
    a->data == b->data &&
    sameTree(a->left, b->left) &&
    sameTree(a->right, b->right)
    );
}
//one empty, one not = FALSE
else 
    return FALSE;
```

}

Ugh. Just for clearing my conscience, again how would you determine whether tree b is inside tree a?

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Contained AS-IS (same shape), or has all nodes with a different shape (this calls for another algorithm)? BTW, you're missing the part where you search for the root of b in a, but I assume you've left this out because it's obvious.

Answer (score 2):

```
int in(struct node* outer, struct node* inner){
    if(inner == null){
        return true; // say every tree contains the empty tree
    } else if(outer == null){
        return false;
    } else if(same(outer, inner)){
        return true;
    } else return in(outer->left, inner) || in(outer->right, inner);
}
```

We must not use the OP's sameTree but rather this function:

```
int same(struct node* outer, struct node* inner){
    return !inner || outer && outer->data == inner->data && same(outer->left, inner->left) && same(outer->right, inner->right);
}
```

Or, more verbosely,

```
int same(struct node* outer, struct node* inner){
    if(inner == null){
        return true;
    } else if(outer == null){
        return false;
    } else if(outer->data == inner->data){
        return same(outer->left, inner->left) && same(outer->right, inner->right);
    } else return false;
}
```

Comment: Right. This looks a lot better than mine, but `sameTree` should also be changed, it will not work sub trees.

Comment: Sorry? The sameTree OP provides looks correct: two null trees are the same, a null tree is not the same as a non-null tree, and two non-null trees are the same if they have the same root-level data and if their children are the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: See my example on Amarghosh's answer. this `sameTree` is correct for equality, but not to check containment.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I did not understand what it mean for a tree to contain another: you mean that the two trees' intersection is equal to the inner tree, whereas I was additionally requiring that subtracting the inner from the outer produce a connected graph. That was what you meant by "A still contains B if A has children where B has nodes." I withdraw my answer.

Comment: Dont! it's very good. Just add a comment saying `sameTree` should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you want the same tree with the same structure, contains in `a`:

For one, if `b` is null and `a` isn't, a contains `b` (you should check that in your last `else`).
Second, these aren't binary search trees (unsorted), so to check if b is inside a you should also traverse a (assuming you rename the function):

```
int containsTree(struct node *a, struct node *b){
//both empty = TRUE
if(a == NULL && b == NULL)
        return TRUE;
//both not empty, compare them

else if(a != NULL && b != NULL){
    return(
      // sameTree should be changed to allow nulls, as below
      sameTree(a, b)
      // check recursively
      || containsTree(a->left, b)
      || containsTree(a->right, b)
    );
//one empty, one not = FALSE
else 
    return B == NULL;
```

Comment: I think you left a trailing _&&_ after _sameTree(a,b)_

Answer (score 1):

To check if tree `A` is contained as-is in tree `B`, find the node `C` in `B` such that `C.data == A.data`. If there is no such node, `A` is not contained in `B`. If `C` exists, check if `A` and `C` are equal using a modified `sameTree` function - one that ignores mismatches between null children of A and non-null children of C (return true if A.left/right is null).

Thanks @Kobi for the correction.

Comment: Not accurate. If A has children where B has nulls, A still contains B.

Comment: His sameTree function is checking for that recursively

Comment: No, it does not. What if a has a left child, `2-A-5` , and b doesn't `NULL-B-5` ? It will check `2` vs `NULL` , and return false.

Comment: Ya, you are right - will edit the post to reflect that. (I'm talking about A in B and you are talking about B in A - that confused me for a moment).

Comment: While you're at it, in this case there can be many `C` nodes, but this is a minor comment :)